# how can I add duplicated rows to a Pandas DF?

Tags: python, pandas

I appreciate the help in advance!

The question may seem weird at first so let me illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

I have this df of cities and abbreviations:

[image]

I need to add another column called 'Queries' and those queries are on a list as follows:

`queries = ['Document Management','Document Imaging','Imaging Services']`

The trick though is that I need to duplicate my df rows for each query in the list. For instance, for row 0 I have `PHOENIX, AZ`. I now need 3 rows saying `PHOENIX, AZ, 'query[n]'`.

Something that would look like this:

[image]

Of course I created that manually but I need to scale it for a large number of cities and a large list of queries.

This sounds simple but I've been trying for some hours now I don't see how to engineer any code for it. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add code as code and not screenshots

Comment: Also, does the original dataframe come from somewhere, or do you create it using `pd.Dataframe()` ?

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace, my apologies for the screenshots. Yes, the dataframe comes from bigquery. It's a small table I have stored with city names and other related data. The list of queries I am creating it from a column in a excel file, which I uploaded to my notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way, using `.explode()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'City_Name': ['Phoenix', 'Tucson', 'Mesa', 'Los Angeles'],
                   'State': ['AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'CA']})

# 'Query' is a column of tuples
df['Query'] = [('Doc Mgmt', 'Imaging', 'Services')] * len(df.index)

# ... and explode 'unpacks' the tuples, putting one item on each line
df = df.explode('Query')
print(df)

     City_Name State     Query
0      Phoenix    AZ  Doc Mgmt
0      Phoenix    AZ   Imaging
0      Phoenix    AZ  Services
1       Tucson    AZ  Doc Mgmt
1       Tucson    AZ   Imaging
1       Tucson    AZ  Services
2         Mesa    AZ  Doc Mgmt
2         Mesa    AZ   Imaging
2         Mesa    AZ  Services
3  Los Angeles    CA  Doc Mgmt
3  Los Angeles    CA   Imaging
3  Los Angeles    CA  Services
```

Comment: If I could accept this myself I would... beautiful. Just wondering if there is a way of skipping the `df['Query'] = ... * len(df.index)` part (could be just `... * len(df)` btw). I was poking at `.merge` and `concat`, but that approach would also need usage of `[df] * amount_of_queries` which is kind of the same just in reverse

Comment: We need to put the tuple (or list) of (Doc Mgmt, Imaging, Services) into each row of the 'Query' column in order to use explode in the next step.  That's why I have a list (with one tuple) multiplied by a length.  As you noted, there are many ways to create the new Query column.

Answer (score 1):

new to python myself, but I would get around it by creating n (n=# of unique query values) identical data frames without "Query". Then for each of the data frame, create a new column with one of the "Query" values. Finally, stack all data frames together using `append`. A short example:

```
adf1 = pd.DataFrame([['city1','sate1'],['city2','state2']])
adf2 = adf1

adf1['query'] = 'doc management'
adf2['query'] = 'doc imaging'

df = adf1.append(adf2)
```

Another method if there are many types of queries.
Creating a dummy column, say 'key', in both the original data frame and the query data frame, and merge the two on 'key'.

```
adf = pd.DataFrame([['city1','state1'],['city2','state2']])
q = pd.DataFrame([['doc management'],['doc imaging']])

adf['key'] = 'key'
q['key'] = 'key'

df = pd.merge(adf, q, on='key', how='outer')
```

More advanced users should have better ways. This is a temporary solution if you are in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely go with [jsmart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431645/1453822), but posting this as an exercise.

This can also be achieved by exporting the original cities/towns dataframe (`df`) to a list or records, manually duplicating each one for each query then reconstructing the final dataframe.

The entire thing can fit in a single line, and is even relatively readable if you can follow what's going on ;)

```
pd.DataFrame([{**record, 'query': query}
               for query in queries
               for record in df.to_dict(orient='records')])
```